# Como recuperar a data atualizada em batch

Tags: batch

Eu fiz um arquivo bat que altera a data do windows.

Porém, também preciso de outro arquivo bat, para quando executado, ele recupere a data atualizada.

Como proceder?

Comment: O que já tentou até aqui Clara?

Comment: o que pensei no primeiro momento era salvar a data em um arquivo de texto antes dela ser alterada.mas não consegui salvar.E não sei se so existe essa solução, achei que tinha alguma variavel de ambiente do windows que ja traga atualizada a data em tempo real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Salvar a data é possível, mas o melhor é **sincronizar** a **<kbd>`data/hora`</kbd>** via **internet**, onde é possível se obter atualizada de forma mais prática e precisa, para isso, use esse  **<kbd>`código`</kbd>**:

```bat
@echo off & color 0a && setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

tzutil /s "E. South America Standard Time"
w32tm /query /status 2>nul >nul 

if not !errorlevel! == 0  (       
    w32tm /register && net start w32time
    w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:a.ntp.br /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update
    w32tm /resync /force /nowait &&  net stop w32time 
    w32tm /unregister  
   ) else (
    w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:a.ntp.br /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update
    w32tm /resync /force /nowait &&  net stop w32time 
   )
```

Comment: Muito boa a solução, acho que eu só mudaria o fato de parar e desregistrar o serviço sempre, para fazer isso somente quando a própria solução iniciar o serviço (*If*). E também, na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/windows-time-service-tools-and-settings), a opção `/resync` não tem uma subopção `/force`.

Comment: @Pedro Gaspar, não sou muito fã de manter serviços e/ou registros quando não estão em uso, ou o seu uso é eventual. o ` **/force** `, existe, adicione qualquer complemento q não tenha suporte no w32tm , e vai te exibir a mensagem de  **erro:" _Os seguintes argumentos não eram esperados:_"**

Comment: **Manter serviço:** mas se ele já estava sendo executado, não seria melhor "manter como encontrou"? / **/force**: Verdade: [PowerTip: Force Time Resync with PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/05/28/powertip-force-time-resync-with-powershell/).

Comment: @Pedro Gaspar, Boa!!, tendi, agora mantem como encontrou... Gostei, obrigado!